# display bytes from database as image in imageview in javafx

Tags: database, javafx, imageview, byte

please I have been stuck on how to convert my stored images from my
database and display it as an image in imageview in javafx.

All the
previously asked questions have not helped me.
I'm using objectdb as my database
I also used fxml to build my GUI

```
for (Person p : person) {
            name.setText(p.getName());
            gender.setText(p.getGender());

            byte[] byteArray = p.getImage();
            image.setImage(new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray)));

}
```

Comment: So what happens when you run the code you posted?

Comment: When i run my code, i get the name and gender returned from the database, but the imageview box remains empty.

Answer (score 2):

I'll show a detailed step on saving to the database using a file chooser and writing an image to a file in a directory(folder) on your hard drive, and also displaying it to imageview in fmxl  GUI.

The following below are triggered during a button event or initialized
from the controller

```
FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
        choose.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);
File file = choose.showOpenDialog(null);
        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            byte[] b;
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(262144)) {
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", out);
                out.flush();
                b = out.toByteArray();
            }
EntityService service = new EntityService();
Person p = new Person();
            p.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            p.setImage(b);
            service.putPerson(p);
} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




Person p = service.getPerson();
        byte[] byteArray = p.getImage();
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(in);
        image.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(read, null));


String output = "C:\\java\\images\\1.jpg";
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output)) {
            fos.write(byteArray);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException : " + ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException : " + ioe);
        }
```